# Error Serializing Observable Collection

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-store-apps, observablecollection, datacontractserializer

I have an observable collection I am trying to serialize to disk.  The error that is received is :

```
 Type 'VisuallySpeaking.Data.GrammarList' with data contract name
 'GrammarList:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/VisuallySpeaking.Data'
 is not expected. Consider using a DataContractResolver or add any
 types not known statically to the list of known types - for example,
 by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the
 list of known types passed to
 DataContractSerializer."}  System.Exception
 {System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException}
```

Here is my data object:

```
namespace VisuallySpeaking.Data
{

    [CollectionDataContract]
    public class GrammarList : ObservableCollection<GrammarDataObject>
{
    public GrammarList() : base()
    {
        Add(new GrammarDataObject("My Name", "My name is","Assets/SampleAssets/MyName.png"));
        Add(new GrammarDataObject("Where is", "Where is",""));
        Add(new GrammarDataObject("Dog", "I have a dog","/Assets/SampleAssets/westie.jpg"));
    }
  }

  [DataContract]
  public class GrammarDataObject :  VisuallySpeaking.Common.BindableBase
  {
      private string _Name;
      private string _SpeakingText;
      private string _ImagePath;


      public GrammarDataObject(string Name, string SpeakingText, string ImagePath)
      {
          this.Name = Name;
          this.SpeakingText = SpeakingText;
          this.ImagePath = ImagePath;
      }

      [DataMember]
      public string Name
      {
          get { return _Name; }
          set
          {
              if (this._Name != value)
              {
                  this._Name = value;
                  this.OnPropertyChanged("Name");
              }
          }
      }

      [DataMember]
      public string SpeakingText
      {
          get { return _SpeakingText; }
          set
          {
              if (this._SpeakingText != value)
              {
                  this._SpeakingText = value;
                  this.OnPropertyChanged("SpeakingText");
              }
          }
      }

      [DataMember]
      public string ImagePath
      {
          get { return _ImagePath; }
          set
          {
              if (this._ImagePath != value)
              {
                  this._ImagePath = value;
                  this.OnPropertyChanged("ImagePath");
              }
          }
      }
  }
```

Based on Fresh's comments, I have added BindableBase in here as well.

```
namespace VisuallySpeaking.Common
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Implementation of <see cref="INotifyPropertyChanged"/> to simplify models.
    /// </summary>
    [Windows.Foundation.Metadata.WebHostHidden]
    [DataContract(IsReference = true)]
    public abstract class BindableBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Multicast event for property change notifications.
        /// </summary>
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        /// <summary>
        /// Checks if a property already matches a desired value.  Sets the property and
        /// notifies listeners only when necessary.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T">Type of the property.</typeparam>
        /// <param name="storage">Reference to a property with both getter and setter.</param>
        /// <param name="value">Desired value for the property.</param>
        /// <param name="propertyName">Name of the property used to notify listeners.  This
        /// value is optional and can be provided automatically when invoked from compilers that
        /// support CallerMemberName.</param>
        /// <returns>True if the value was changed, false if the existing value matched the
        /// desired value.</returns>
        protected bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] String propertyName = null)
        {
            if (object.Equals(storage, value)) return false;

            storage = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
            return true;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Notifies listeners that a property value has changed.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="propertyName">Name of the property used to notify listeners.  This
        /// value is optional and can be provided automatically when invoked from compilers
        /// that support <see cref="CallerMemberNameAttribute"/>.</param>
        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            var eventHandler = this.PropertyChanged;
            if (eventHandler != null)
            {
                eventHandler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I assume that I have somehow marked my `GrammarList` class incorrectly, but it escapes me as to how to resolve.

**UPDATE:**
Following the error message (of course), I added the KnowTypeAttribute and it appeared to work:

```
[CollectionDataContract(Name = "GrammarList"),KnownType(typeof(GrammarList))]
public class GrammarList : ObservableCollection<GrammarDataObject>
```

Again, thanks to Fresh, I updated the CollectionDataContract with the Name="GrammarList", but now the issue comes when I rehydrate the XML file from disk.  I get the following error message:

> Expecting element 'GrammarList' from namespace
>   'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/VisuallySpeaking.Data'..
>   Encountered 'Element'  with name 'GrammarDataObject', namespace
>   'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/VisuallySpeaking.Data'.

The serialized XML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>    
<GrammarDataObject xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/VisuallySpeaking.Data" i:type="GrammarList">        
    <GrammarDataObject xmlns:z="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" z:Id="i1">    
         <ImagePath>Assets/SampleAssets/MyName.png</ImagePath>    
         <Name>My Name</Name>    
         <SpeakingText>My name is</SpeakingText>    
    </GrammarDataObject>


    <GrammarDataObject xmlns:z="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" z:Id="i3">    
        <ImagePath/>  
        <Name>Where is</Name>    
        <SpeakingText>Where is</SpeakingText>    
     </GrammarDataObject>


    <GrammarDataObject xmlns:z="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" z:Id="i4">    
        <ImagePath>/Assets/SampleAssets/westie.jpg</ImagePath>    
        <Name>Dog</Name>    
        <SpeakingText>I have a dog</SpeakingText>    
    </GrammarDataObject>    
</GrammarDataObject>
```

Why is the XML outer tags not listed as "GrammarList"?  I would assume that is what the deserializer is looking for.  When I manually edit the serialized xml to place GrammarList as the outside tags, it deserializes appropriately.  I feel sure I am missing something again!

**UPDATE AGAIN**
When I was serializing I had the following code:

```
DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(GrammarDataObject));
```

I changed it to serialize to GrammarList and presto, fixed!!!  thanks for the help Fresh.

```
DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(GrammarList));
```

Comment: You should mark the answer of Fresh as the accepted answer and upvote him when you can. That way, readers like me will know right away that you're problem is solved! ;) That's the way to go on SO. I also suggest you to have a look to our help section : http://stackoverflow.com/help Good Clear question by the way.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the XML output, it looks like the name of the collection is lost when its de-serialized.

Try setting the Name property on the CollectionDataContract i.e.

```
[CollectionDataContract(Name="GrammarList"),KnownType(typeof(GrammarList))]
public class GrammarList : ObservableCollection<GrammarDataObject>
```

Comment: I actually did mark BindableBase.  I am not sure how to put code in here, so I will update the original post with the BindableBase code.

Comment: I tried adding in the [field:NonSerialized] attribute, but it is not recognized in winrt (and I cant resolve it to anything).

Comment: Added a KnownAttribute tag, and it then serialized.  Had additional issues though.  Please see edited post.

Comment: Thanks Fresh - I added the Name Property and it changed nothing on the rehydration side.  Weird behavior...would think if you can serialize, you could deserialize in the exact same manner.

Comment: @user1558885 So when you added the Name property, was the serialised XML exactly the same as before? I would expect to see a Name attribute in there. Also how exactly are you performing the serialization i.e. what is you exact method call?

Comment: AHAAA!  I found the issue.  I was serializing and passing a typeof(GrammarDataObject).  Therefore it was placing that on the outer tags.  I will update post.  thanks for your help Fresh. :)

Comment: Woot! Yes, see my last comment. In your post it dawned on me that you didn't specify exactly how you were performing the serialization i.e. how you were calling initialising the DataContractSerializer. Doh! Glad this issue is resolved, and good work adding the updates to the post!